# Python - Updating pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to update pandas, but I get the following errors after running the updgrade.  What should I do?

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pandas

  Downloading pandas-0.14.0.tar.gz (6.5MB): 6.5MB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pandas
    Running from numpy source directory.
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    non-existing path in '/private/var/folders/3k/54tzj0597zg8wdtf4509g58m0000gn/T/easy_install-bUVakZ/numpy-1.8.1/numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'
    non-existing path in '/private/var/folders/3k/54tzj0597zg8wdtf4509g58m0000gn/T/easy_install-bUVakZ/numpy-1.8.1/numpy/lib': 'benchmarks'
    Could not locate executable gfortran
    Could not locate executable f95
    Could not locate executable f90
    Could not locate executable f77
    Could not locate executable xlf90
    Could not locate executable xlf
    Could not locate executable ifort
    Could not locate executable ifc
    Could not locate executable g77
    Could not locate executable g95
    Could not locate executable pgfortran
    don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'posix'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that perhaps you installed Pandas through a package like Anaconda or Enthought? or some other pre-compiled package? you will need to see how that package manger says to do it.. I Imagine you are on Windows and do not have Fortran installed?

Comment: I am using mac.  I use pip and easy_install.  I think it may have come already installed?  I'm not sure on that.

Comment: how did you do the original install? Something changed.. so Fortran can't be found?

Comment: Even if you didn't use Anaconda before, maybe you should use it now. It does not interfere or interact with whatever other installations may or may not exist on your system. Granted, that's not a satisfying solution to this question, but one that would let you do the upgrade and keep working.

Comment: I just installed Anaconda and everything works!  Thanks.